# Why isn't the code area of a question resizable?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes users post large blocks of code. So there are scroll bars given in both vertical and (or) horizontal directions.
Well, scrolling horizontally and reading the code is sometimes cumbersome.
So, why doesn't SO have the option to resize horizontally?

Comment: It's a feature request so I edited the tag, you might want to change the style of the question to comply with it? Good idea BTW!

Comment: @GeorgeStocker what about ASCII art? =) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work/23877420#23877420

Comment: i feel the same way. i think allowing us to collapse the right sidebar would open more room for Post Content, and thus more room for Code Example text areas. I proposed this as a feature request here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263040/allow-collapse-of-sidebar-to-have-more-room-for-code-examples-text-area

Comment: I added a extension to chrome to fix this feel free to pm me with any comment. link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-codewrap/dpjamcfibggfkehfeopaoodbciklmfph?utm_source=gmail