# Allow collapse of sidebar to have more room for Code Examples text area

Tags: feature-request

Consider allowing users to collapse/expand the right sidebar, to allow for more space for Post Content, specifically to allow more room for Code Examples text area.

Developers hate scrolling left/right in code.

Comment: or at least allow Word-Wrap when viewing code example text areas

Comment: Or people could just stop using Really Long Lines. And also stop using Objective-C.

Comment: even if we could widen the browser window to make more room for Post Content area, that'd help. But as it is now, the Post Content area (and Code Example areas) are fixed widths.

Comment: I find the Stack Exchange one-size-fits-all layout a bit frustrating. Why can't at least the code example box be expandable width?

Comment: I added a extension to chrome to fix this feel free to pm me with any comment. link https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-codewrap/dpjamcfibggfkehfeopaoodbciklmfph?utm_source=gmail